# Google Chrome not recognizing First-Party Cookies?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, cookies

I hope someone can point out what I am missing here.

My problem is illustrated in this image:
[Chrome not showing first-party-cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NBa9.png)

I have a nodejs / express based application which sets a cookie. I can see the page which is retrieved has the following header:

```
Set-Cookie:firstParty=IsWhatIShouldBe; Max-Age=216; Domain=firstparty.cookie.com; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 22 Jan 2016 14:22:15 GMT; HttpOnly
```

The domain I am accessing is firstparty.cookie.com

According to google, https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?hl=en, a cookie will be marked as first-party when: "First-party cookies are set by the site domain listed in the address bar"

As you can see, the domain I am accessing AND the domain parameter in the cookie are the same, still in Chrome's developer tools, under resources and then cookies, the cookie is not identified as a first-party cookie.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I've been looking at this all wrong. First-Party column does not indicate wether a cookie is a "first-party-cookie". But it's there to show if the new "First-Party-Only" parameter is set on the cookie. The column was introduced late 2015, but the feature to really support this setting has yet to come (probably Chrome 50+)

For more info see on First-Party-Only by Google: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4672634709082112
And the related Chromium issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=459154

Answer (score 0):

Cookie with domain `.firstparty.cookie.com` is not firstparty cookie, because it's available to all subdomains. But `firstparty.cookie.com` is, because it can be used by only one domain. Check where you get extra dot in `domain` field of cookie

Comment: I understand, the funny thing is in my Set-Cookie header you see _Domain=firstparty.cookie.com_. Dev-tools seem to be adding that specific dot there. I think this complies with  RFC 6265 - http://bayou.io/draft/cookie.domain.html Any suggestions as of where the dot comes from?